# Thinkpad External Keyboard - Fn Ctrl switch

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

Just bought a new Thinkpad External Keyboard with Trackpoint.

I'm at lost about how to enable the Fn functionality and had it switched with Ctrl, from which the notebook keyboard have by switching it in BIOS.

I've checked through `xev` that the Fn button is not even signalling any keycode.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Only on the hardware layer, because FN key is just HW switch, and after pressing, different codes are sent when pressing keys (for a system it is like you have 2x more keys on the keyboard).
There is one guy in the world, that was able to switch it, but he knows exactly what he was doing.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think is possible https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/70gk4v/swap_ctrl_fn_keys_on_the_thinkpad_compact_usb/

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions from https://github.com/lentinj/tp-compact-keyboard. Briefly, this command should enable the top-row function keys:

```
echo 0 > /sys/bus/hid/devices/*17EF\:604*/fn_lock
```